# Can I rewrite my Java struts2 Action validation() function as an Action-validation XML?

Tags: forms, jsp, struts, validation

I'm currently working on validation for a login form.

I have a **WORKING** set of validations within my action:

```
// SNIP!!!!
    @Override
    public void validate() 
    { 
        if (userBean.getUserName().length() == 0)
            { addFieldError("userBean.userName", "Username is required."); }

        if (userBean.getPassword().length() == 0)
            { addFieldError("userBean.password", "Password is required."); }
        else if (!(
                    User
                        .findUser(userBean.getUserName())
                        .getPassword()
                        .equals(userBean.getPassword())
                ))  
            { addFieldError("userBean.password", "Password is invalid."); }
    }
// SNIP!!!!
```

I am trying to figure out whether I can rewrite this into a validation XML

This what my XML currently looks like

```
<!-- //src/hu/flux/user/LoginUserAction-validation.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
 <validator type="requiredstring">
  <param name="fieldname">userBean.userName</param>
  <message>Username is required.</message>
 </validator>
 <validator type="requiredstring">
  <param name="fieldname">userBean.password</param>
  <message>Password is required.</message>
 </validator>
  <validator type="fieldexpression">
  <param name="fieldname">userBean.password</param>
  <param name="expression"><![CDATA[
  (
   User
    .findUser(userBean.userName)
    .getPassword()
    .equals(userBean.password)
   ) 
  ]]></param>
        <!-- This error message is just for debugging -->
  <message>

    Password is invalid. 
    ${userBean.password} received. 
    ${(
   User
    .findUser(userBean.userName)
    .getPassword()
    .equals(userBean.password)
   )} expected.
  </message>
 </validator>
</validators>
```

When I try using the XML instead of the JAVA, and then submit any password an error message like this is displayed on the form:

```
Password is invalid. sdfdsf received. expected.
```

"sdfdsf" could be whatever password I attempted.

Is it possible to do this using a validator XML?  Or do I need to user the validation() function?

(I thought I had this working in the XML, but then for some inexplicable reason it stopped working.)